# Upload code gets executed only once

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to design an application that starts a camera intent, uploads a photo, (and hopefully, work in progress: parse an XML response from the server, then move to another activity and fill in some form fields).

The problem is that so far the upload code is executed the 1st time I run the application, the 2nd time it gets skipped, the 3rd time works fine, 4th skips and so on.

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // buttons
        Button lunchCamBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lunchVerBtn);
        lunchCamBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        Button lunchCaptBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lunchCaptBtn);
        lunchCaptBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    String path;
    String picfname;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);


            Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            String picfname = "bul "+dateFormat.format(date)+" "+rnd.nextInt(90)+".png";


            File output = new File(dir,picfname);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(output));
            path = output.getAbsolutePath();
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), path.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        UploadFiles upld =new UploadFiles(MainActivity.this);
        upld.execute(path.toString());

    }
```

### UploadFiles:

```
public  class UploadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    WeakReference<Activity> mActivityReference;

    public UploadFiles(Activity activity){
        this.mActivityReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean succesz = true;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;
        String selectedPath = params[0];
        String pathToOurFile = selectedPath;
        String urlServer = "http://192.168.0.104/upload2.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToOurFile);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
            InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            connection.setReadTimeout(25000 /* milliseconds */);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
            .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
            + lineEnd);

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            String line = "";
            line = convertStreamToString(stream);
            System.out.print(line);
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return succesz;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Stream Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return total.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if (result && mActivityReference.get() != null) {
            Activity activity = mActivityReference.get();

            Intent iinent= new Intent(activity,TestActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(iinent);
            //activity.finish();
        }
    }}
```

I know now that this issue is caused by the `convertStreamToString` method in class UploadFiles but I can't understand what exactly causes it. When I remove it completely everything works fine. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Dont leave exception blocks empty. This is a common mistake which makes error go invisible. Add logs there.

Answer (score 0):

***The first minor problem:***
Using `available` is basically wrong, though it might work.

**The second minor problem:**
Do not use DataOutputStream here. I guess it is done to be able to write Strings to an OutputStream.

response.setContentType("...; charset=Windows-1252");
   BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "Windows-1252"));

Somehow also specifying the encoding/charset may help.

***Problem with the convertStreamToString:***
In no extra encoding parameter is added to the InputStreamReader, the default platform encoding is used. UTF-8 on Android. That would fail relatively fast.

You might give a less strict single-byte encoding a try to see what happens:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "Windows-1252"));
```

In general encoding is not handled: `URLConnection.getContentEncoding()` maybe is informative.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing couple of things wrong here.

- Don't leave exception blocks empty. It hides all the error. Use Log.e to print that.
- Don't use System.out.println. Use Log.* only for logging.
- Don't use AsyncTask to upload your file. Use IntentService Instead. And using localbroadcastmanager broadcast upload events for your activity to listen. It will be more configuration change friendly.
- Instead of doing all this file upload sorcery yourself. Use httpmime library instead. It works simply awesome on android. I have my apps on production using this. Something like this you have to do.

  ```
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlToUpload);

      MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFileUri);
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
      InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
      ContentBody imageContent = new InputStreamBody(in, "image/jpeg", sourceFile.getName());

      entity.addPart("file", imageContent);
      post.setEntity(entity);

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
  ```
- You will have your everything in 'response' for you to read.

  ```
   String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
  ```
- From here you can download this library http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.5/

Comment: "Don't leave exception blocks empty. It hides all the error. Use Log.e to print that." *Just* logging the error is effectively the same as hiding it. Handle it properly or crash.

Comment: "just logging the error is effectively the same as hiding it" - No It isn't. Many a time we don't want to handle the exception or do something when exception occurs. But its important to know if there is anything wrong happening around. So whatever be the case. One should log the exception trace.

Comment: You wouldn't ship exception handlers that *only* log exceptions, they are essentially the same as ignoring the exceptions

Comment: "You wouldn't ship exception handlers that only log exceptions" - Partially correct i believe. So it was for development phase. I have my one monitor with only logs running. When i see a red colored stack over there. This triggers me of something wrong happening and the entire stack tells me whats going on. And i personally don't rip Log.w and Log.e from my production builds. Rest d,v,i,dw all are removed. But again this is separate thing to discuss from this thread. You should make a question on stackexchange.

Comment: That is not worth asking as it is mostly style-oriented. Personally i leave any log output deemed useful on a case-per-case basis but that's just me. I was worrying about you suggesting log-only handlers in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service for file uploads.

I handle all the response-related logic inside the Broadcast receiver, where I'm waiting for the upload responses.